# Traversing a nested dict-like structure, keeping track of each path from root to leaf (Python)

Tags: python, object, recursion, path, traversal

I'm trying to traverse an object that has arbitrarily deeply nested leaves, getting the path of each root node to leaf. An example of this might be:

```
class Field (object):
    def __init__(self, name, subfields=None):
        self.name = name
        self.subfields = subfields


f1 = Field("username")
f2 = Field("ip_address")
f3 = Field("song_id")
f11 = Field("song_length")
f10 = Field("misc_attrs", subfields=[f3, f11])

f4 = Field("event_time")
f5 = Field("song_name", subfields=[f1,f2])
f6 = Field("user_song_upload", subfields=[f10])

input_list = [f4,f5,f6]
```

My goal is to produce a list `output` of lists, where each list in `output` represents a path from the root node to the leaf.  So in the example above, we'd have the following output:

```
[["event_time"],["song_name","username"],["song_name","ip_address"],["user_song_upload","misc_attrs","song_id"],["user_song_upload","misc_attrs","song_length"]]
```

I have a function that will return all of the leaf nodes, but I'm having trouble keeping track of the complete path for each node. Here is what I have so far:

```
def get_leaf_paths(input_list, output = [], path=[]):
    for x in input_list:
        if not x.subfields:
            # we have a leaf
            path.append(x.name)
            output.append(path) 
            # next line clears the leaf from our last path
            path = path[:-1]

        else:
            # we don't have a leaf node, and need to iterate on the subfields
            path.append(x.name)
            get_leaf_paths(x.subfields, output, path)
    return output
```

However, this results in paths being built incorrectly (e.g., two adjacent top-level nodes will end up in the same inner list in the output:

```
[['event_time'],
 ['song_name', 'username', 'user_song_upload', 'misc_attrs', 'song_id'],
 ['song_name', 'ip_address'],
 ['song_name', 'username', 'user_song_upload', 'misc_attrs', 'song_id'],
 ['song_name', 'username', 'user_song_upload', 'misc_attrs', 'song_length']]
```

Comment: Your dictionary is not a valid dictionary, for example the keys "event_time" and "browser" have no value.

Comment: Thanks - I'm amending this to make it clear we're talking about a more generic object here, not a dict.

Comment: Your 'more generic object' still isn't valid Python though. Please provide a concrete and valid example. If you only provide some abstract pseudo-object, all that can be provided as an answer is some description of what you need - which you already gave us. Your example code refers to some `input_list`, but you provide no example of such a list.

Comment: Alright, I've edited the question so my object is valid Python and the provided function can run without errors on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct an appropriate base case to simplify the code. Try the following:

```py
def get_leaf_paths(lst):
    if not lst: # empty list or None
        return [[]]
    return [[f.name, *path] for f in lst for path in get_leaf_paths(f.subfields)]

print(get_leaf_paths(input_list))
```

In the code, the base case is "an empty list or None", i.e., when `subfields` is passed to the function but `subfields` is actually `None`. This will be the case when the function is called at a leaf node.

Output:

```
[['event_time'], ['song_name', 'username'], ['song_name', 'ip_address'], ['user_song_upload', 'misc_attrs', 'song_id'], ['user_song_upload', 'misc_attrs', 'song_length']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to apply this to a very deep structure and recursion (like @j1-lee suggest in their otherwise very clean implementation) is not an option, this works:

```py
def get_leaf_paths(lst):
    stack, l, i = [], lst, 0
    while l and len(l) > i:
        if l[i].subfields:
            stack.append((l, i))
            l, i = l[i].subfields, 0
        else:
            yield [x[n].name for x, n in stack] + [l[i].name]
            i += 1
        if i >= len(l):
            l, i = stack.pop()
            i += 1


print(list(get_leaf_paths(input_list)))
```

Result:

```
[['event_time'], ['song_name', 'username'], ['song_name', 'ip_address'], ['user_song_upload', 'misc_attrs', 'song_id'], ['user_song_upload', 'misc_attrs', 'song_length']]
```